# Difference drawing random numbers from distributions R

Tags: r, sampling

I am comparing these two forms of drawing random numbers from a beta and a Gaussian distribution. What are their differences? Why are they different?

The first way (`_1`) simulates from a Uniform(0,1) and then applies the inverse CDF of the Beta (Normal) distribution on those uniform draws to get draws from the Beta (Normal) distribution.

While the second way (`_2`) uses the default function to generate random numbers from the distribution.

#### Beta Distribution

```
set.seed(1)
beta_1 <- qbeta(runif(1000,0,1), 2, 5)
set.seed(1)
beta_2 <- rbeta(1000, 2,5)

> summary(beta_1); summary(beta_2)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.009481 0.164551 0.257283 0.286655 0.387597 0.895144 
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.006497 0.158083 0.261649 0.284843 0.396099 0.841760
```

Here every number is different.

#### Normal distribution

```
set.seed(1)
norm_1 <- qnorm(runif(1000, 0,1), 0, 0.1)
set.seed(1)
norm_2 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 0.1)

> summary(norm_1); summary(norm_2)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.3008048 -0.0649125 -0.0041975  0.0009382  0.0664868  0.3810274 
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-0.300805 -0.069737 -0.003532 -0.001165  0.068843  0.381028
```

Here the numbers are almost the same except in the mean and median

Shouldn't all be equal? Because I am generating random numbers from distributions with the same parameters

Comment: Were you expecting the exact same numbers? Because the functions use different random sampling techniques you will never get the same numbers from different r* functions using the same seed. There will be natural statistical variation. If you plot `qqplot(beta_1, beta_2); abline(0,1, col="red")` you can see that the distributions are pretty similar. This is probably more of a statistical question for [stats.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MrFlick, yes I was expecting the same numbers ): But are both "correct" methods for generating random numbers from those distributions, right?

Comment: Yes. Theoretically in the long term they should both draw from an equivalent distribution. But because of the way computers generate random numbers, these two different methods wont produce the exact same individual observations.

Comment: For the beta distribution, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975300/speed-of-random-sampling-from-distribution-in-r/65975421#65975421

Comment: Are you asking a statistical question or a computing question?  Some methods are not very accurate or fast.  Usually the built-in method in a statistical computing platform has been optimized for both, so you should be careful about implementing any alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your question boils down to the assumption about the random number generator.  If `rnorm` used the same RNG as `runif` under the hood, then your expectation would hold.  It does not use the same RNG.  The normal distribution RNG and uniform RNG are separate.  See `?RNGkind`.  Without that exact match, you are left with the statistical tests below:

Is the mean of norm_1 different from the mean of norm_2?

```r
t.test(x = norm_1, y = norm_2)
```

p-value > 0.05 indicates there is insufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis that the means are equal at the 0.05 type I error level

Are the distributions different?

```r
ks.test(x = norm_1, y = norm_2)
```

p-value > 0.05 indicates there is insufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis that the distributions are equal at the 0.05 type I error level

Comment: I'm confused by your mention of the RNG kind. While different RNG kinds will obviously give different sequences, usually one uses a single RNG in the same piece of code. What matters is how the RNG output (typically a very long integer) is transformed into samples from the desired distribution. For example there are several ways to convert the output of the RNG into a std normal distribution, e.g. the inverse CDF, Box-Muller, Ziggurat, etc. The choice between them often takes accuracy and computational cost into account. The inverse CDF is often a bad choice.

Comment: ... Even for the same RNG and seed, generating normal samples from the inverse CDF will give a different sequence than, e.g., Box-Muller.

Comment: @LucaCiti My point was that, in the RNGkind function, there are different algorithm options for the base generator and the normal generator.  Sextus Empiricus shows in his answer that the normal generator, when the inversion algorithm is selected, is sampling from the same base stream, just more often.  If a different algorithm, other than inversion, is selected in RNGkind, that would not be true.

Comment: I thought you were referring to the `kind` part of RNGkind, while you are referring to the `kind`+`normal.kind` combination. I think I was especially confused by "if rnorm used the same RNG as runif under the hood". Incidentally, it's a bit of an R quirk to conflate the two into the same function. In most languages and libraries the base RNG (one for all distributions) and the sampling transform (one per distribution) are kept separate while R puts the transformation for the normal (but no other distribution) in a special place together with the base RNG.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to sample a Bernoulli parameter at home using two different ways.

1. I flip a coin and assign 1 to heads and 0 to tails
2. I roll a six sided dice and assign the result 1 to a roll of the 3 highest numbers and the result 0 to a roll of the 3 lowest numbers.

I did this only twenty times instead of thousand times but the principle is the same. I got the following results:

|  | result 0 | result 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Method 1 | 11 | 9 |
| Method 2 | 8 | 12 |

Q: Why did I not get the same result for both methods?

A: Well, it is of course because they are samples and are supposed to be variable everytime.

If I would be able to reset some random seed to remove the variability, then this still doesn't matter because they are different methods.

---

#### Why is there no use of [inverse transform sampling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)?

The normal distribution actually does use inverse transform sampling. The following command returns the same value of `0.3735462`

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(1,1,1)
set.seed(1)
qnorm(runif(1),1,1)
```

Also the `rbeta` uses inverse transform sampling and the following returns the same `0.7344913` and `0.2655087`, which are only different by the relationship Y = 1-X (so internally there is some inversion)

```
alpha = 1
beta = 1
set.seed(1)
rbeta(1,alpha,beta)
set.seed(1)
qbeta(runif(1),alpha,beta)
```

The beta function becomes different when when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not both equal to one. This is because the inverse sampling is not very efficient and the the `rbeta` function will do some algorithm that creates the sample in a different way. Below is a code with the algorithm for the case that $min(\alpha,\beta) \leq 1$.

See for more about the algorithm: Hung, Ying-Chao, Narayanaswamy Balakrishnan, and Yi-Te Lin. "Evaluation of beta generation algorithms." Communications in Statistics-Simulation and Computation 38.4 (2009): 750-770.

[image: comparison]

You can see a few points that are calculated differently. The algorithm has a few steps where it starts redrawing random numbers, and it does this because redrawing numbers is easier than computing the inverse transform for a difficult case.

```
alpha = 0.9
beta = 0.9

#### Cheng's BC algorithm 
### used if min(alpha,beta)<=1

### initialize
set.seed(1)
p = min(alpha,beta)
q = max(alpha,beta)
a = p+q
b = p^-1
delta = 1+q-p
k1 = delta*(0.0138889+0.0416667*p)/(q*b-0.777778)
k2 = 0.25 + (0.5+0.25/delta)*p


sample = function() {
  ### Perform steps of algorithm in a loop
  step = 1
  while(step<6) {
    if (step == 1) {
      U1 = runif(1)
      U2 = runif(1)
      if (U1 < 0.5) 
        {step = 2}
      else
        {step = 3}
    }
    if (step == 2) {
       Y = U1*U2
       Z = U1*Y
       if (0.25*U2 + Z-Y >= k1) {
         step = 1
       } else {
         step = 5
       }
    }
    if (step == 3) {
      Z = U1^2*U2
      if (Z > 0.25)  {
         step = 4
      } else {
         V = b*log(U1/(1-U1))
         W = q*exp(V)
         step = 6
      }
    }
    if (step == 4) {
      if (Z < k2) {
        step = 5
      } else {
        step = 1
      }
    }
    if (step == 5) {
      V = b*log(U1/(1-U1))
      W = q*exp(V)
      if (a*(log(a/(p+W))+V) - 1.3862944 < log(Z)) {
        step = 1
      } else {
        step = 6
      }
    }
  }
  if (q == alpha) {
    X = W/(p+W)
  } else {
    X = p/(p+W)
  }
  return(X)
}

sample()

n = 20
beta_orig = sapply(1:n,function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  rbeta(1,alpha,beta)
})
beta_quantile = sapply(1:n,function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  qbeta(runif(1),alpha,beta)
})
beta_BC = sapply(1:n,function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  sample()
})

plot(beta_orig,beta_BC, pch = 1, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1))
points(beta_orig,beta_quantile, col = 2, pch = 3)

legend(0.3,1, c("rbeta compared to inverse transform sampling", "rbeta compared to manual"), pch=c(3,1), col = c(2,1), cex = 0.85)
```

#### Some weird effect

In the code above I was resetting the random seed for each computation. The inverse transform is only the same for the first number. When you compute multiple numbers then only the first number is the same.

The following code

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(6,1,1)
set.seed(1)
qnorm(runif(6),1,1)
              
set.seed(2)
rnorm(6,1,1)
set.seed(2)
qnorm(runif(6),1,1)
```

returns

```
[1] 0.3735462 1.1836433 0.1643714 2.5952808 1.3295078 0.1795316
[1] 0.3735462 0.6737666 1.1836433 2.3297993 0.1643714 2.2724293
[1]  0.1030855  1.1848492  2.5878453 -0.1303757  0.9197482  1.1324203
[1] 0.10308546 1.53124079 1.18484918 0.03810797 2.58784531 2.58463150
```

What you see here is that `rnorm` function skips a number. The reason is because it samples two random numbers to create more precision.

See these lines in the source ode of the norm_rand() function that R uses  https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/snorm.c

```
define BIG 134217728 /* 2^27 */
    /* unif_rand() alone is not of high enough precision */
    u1 = unif_rand();
    u1 = (int)(BIG*u1) + unif_rand();
    return qnorm5(u1/BIG, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0);
```